# JSON Schema Custom Definition

Tags: json, schema, metadata

Can I have a custom specifier/attribute like "required" keyword to decorate my Json schema fields with custom specifications.

Like for example:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Product",
    "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
            "description": "Name of the product",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0,
            "exclusiveMinimum": true
        },
       "**credit-card**": {
            "**type**": "**number**",
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        }
    },
    "required": ["id", "name", "price"],
    "**confidential**" : ["**credit-card**"]
}
```

Can I have a special keyword called "confidential" to make sure that "credit-card" should not be revealed and/or masked? Does the schema standards allow for such custom metadata keywords?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library you will use to execute the validation. I've used [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv), it allows you to define custom keywords, you can find more information about it [here](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/CUSTOM.md).